# 8 bit CRC help - Automotive

Tags: embedded

Reverse engineering some Automotive CAN data and the CRC is getting me. 
8 bytes per message, with Byte 0 being the CRC.
Byte 1 & 0xF contains a counter [0x0 to 0xF]. The rest of the message is data.

I've tried running lines of data through various CRC calculations but getting nowhere fast. Any help would be appreciated. csv on the link below

I've been running lines of this through reveng and getting the odd match but it's a bit hit and miss

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w7diZetSim7hVV1P-2Qls3DfFkB-57vT

Data here is:
ID,B0,B1,B2...,B7 in Hex

40F8000000C0000000
409C010000C0000000
4030020000C0000000
4054030000C0000000
4047040000C0000000
4023050000C0000000
408F060000C0000000
40EB070000C0000000
40A9080000C0000000
40CD090000C0000000
4061100000C0000000
4005110000C0000000
4016120000C0000000
4072130000C0000000
40DE140000C0000000
40BA150000C0000000

Thanks in advance,
D

Comment: please paste some examples in the question body  so we don't rely on an external file which may be gone at some point

Comment: What CRC versions/polynoms have you already tried? Wikipedia has a nice lists of CRCs and the used polynoms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a CRC? There’s an awful lot of zeros in these samples